# Enviar valor de campo que pertenece a modelo generado en accion de controlador a archivo .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy trabajando en la recuperación de contraseña a traves del correo en MVC C# VS 2017, ya envio el correo, pero tengo un detalle, y es que no logro visualizar los valores de 2 datos dentro del correo que son Nombre y PIN.

Aquí parte del código del controlador Acceso para enviar el correo al usuario que este registrado dentro de la BD:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RecuperaPIN(CorreoViewModel mCorreo)
    {
        CorreoViewModel oVC = new CorreoViewModel();    // Modelo para usuarios
        oVC.iImagen_logo = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Content\assets\images\interfazuzh\UAMZHAGUILAhorizontalCOLOR.jpg";
        oVC.IdImagen_Logo = "AGUILAhorizontalCOLOR";

        oVC.iImagen_1 = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Content\templates\responsive-email.jpg";
        oVC.IdImagen_1 = "responsive-email";

        oVC.iImagen_2 = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Content\templates\mailchimp-logo.jpg";
        oVC.IdImagen_2 = "mailchimp-logo";

        oVC.iImagen_3 = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Content\templates\campaign-monitor-logo.jpg";
        oVC.IdImagen_3 = "campaign-monitor-logo";

        var iToken = Int32.Parse(Session["token"].ToString());
        oVC.resultado = 0;
        try
        {
            using (BDAccesoEntities db = new BDAccesoEntities())
            {
                var lstU = (from u in db.usuario
                            join ua in db.usuario_aplicacion on u.id equals ua.id_usuario
                            join ce in db.catalogo_estatus on u.id_estatus equals ce.id
                            join r in db.catalogo_roles on ua.id_rol equals r.id
                            where u.ccorreo == mCorreo.correo && ua.id_aplicacion == iToken
                            select new { u.id, u.cusuario, u.cnombre, u.capellido_paterno, u.capellido_materno, u.ccorreo, u.id_unidad, u.id_estatus, ua.id_rol, id_estatus_ua = ua.id_estatus }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (lstU == null)   // Cuando el RPE y/o Contraseña no son correctos
                {
                    oVC.resultado = 5;
                    oVC.mensaje = "Datos incorrectos. No tengo registrado CORREO ELECTRONICO capturado, intenta otra vez !"; // Si se recibe un ID que no exista de la aplicación
                }
                else
                {
                    oVC.correo = lstU.ccorreo;
                    oVC.cNombre = lstU.cnombre;
                    switch (lstU.id_estatus)    // ************************* Validamos al Usuario en su estado para estados 1 = Activo, 2 = Inactivo  y 4 = Baja o Eliminado temporal
                    {
                        case 1:
                            oVC.resultado = 1;
                            switch (lstU.id_estatus_ua)
                            {
                                case 2: // Cuando el usuario tiene estado a Activo = 1 pero Inactivo para la aplicación
                                    oVC.resultado = 2;
                                    oVC.mensaje = "Usuario INACTIVO, NO ES posible brindar el servicio.";
                                    break;
                                case 4: // Cuando el usuario tiene estado a Activo = 1 pero Baja Temporal para la aplicación
                                    oVC.resultado = 4;
                                    oVC.mensaje = "Usuario con BAJA TEMPORAL para esta Aplicación, NO ES POSIBLE brindar el servicio desde esta Aplicación.";
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2: // Cuando el usuario tiene estado a Inactivo = 2
                            oVC.resultado = 2;
                            oVC.mensaje = "Usuario INACTIVO, NO ES posible brindar el servicio.";
                            break;
                        case 4: // Cuando el usuario tiene estado de Baja Temporal = 4
                            oVC.resultado = 4;
                            oVC.mensaje = "Usuario DADO DE BAJA, NO ES posible brindar el servicio.";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oVC.resultado = 5;
            oVC.mensaje = "Esto no me lo esperaba... ha ocurrido un error:" + ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }
        if (oVC.resultado > 1)
        {
            Session["mensaje_usuario"] = oVC.mensaje;
            return Redirect("~/Acceso/Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EnviaCorreoElectronico", "Acceso", oVC);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<string> EmailTemplate(string template)
    {
        var templateFilePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/templates/") + template + ".cshtml";
        StreamReader objstreamreaderfile = new StreamReader(templateFilePath);
        var body = await objstreamreaderfile.ReadToEndAsync();
        objstreamreaderfile.Close();
        return body;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EnviaCorreoElectronico(CorreoViewModel model)
    {
        var message = await EmailTemplate("SoportePIN");
        message = message.Replace(model.correo.ToString(), ", este es tu PIN");
        await EnviaCorreo.SendEmailAsync(message, model);
        return Redirect("~/Acceso/Index");
    }
```

Aquí la clase con la que envió el correo SendEmailAsync

```
using System;
public class EnviaCorreo
{

    public async static Task SendEmailAsync(string message, CorreoViewModel correo)
    {
        try
        {
            var _email = "sistemas@contabilidad.mx";
            var _epass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorreoSoporte"];
            var _dispName = "Sistemas Soporte: Este es tu PIN";

            MailMessage mMensaje = new MailMessage();
            mMensaje.To.Add(correo.correo);
            mMensaje.From = new MailAddress(_email, _dispName);
            mMensaje.Subject = correo.cNombre + ", este es tu PIN";
            mMensaje.Body = message;
            mMensaje.IsBodyHtml = true;

            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(message,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

            LinkedResource img1 = new LinkedResource(correo.iImagen_logo, MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);
            img1.ContentId = correo.IdImagen_Logo;
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img1);

            LinkedResource img2 = new LinkedResource(correo.iImagen_1, MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);
            img2.ContentId = correo.IdImagen_1;
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img2);

            LinkedResource img3 = new LinkedResource(correo.iImagen_2, MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);
            img3.ContentId = correo.IdImagen_2;
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img3);

            LinkedResource img4 = new LinkedResource(correo.iImagen_3, MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);
            img4.ContentId = correo.IdImagen_3;
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(img4);

            mMensaje.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Host = "SMTP.office365.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_email, _epass);
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) => { smtp.Dispose(); };
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mMensaje);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Y aquí la forma en que al llamar el campo en el código del cshtml, no me muestra su valor, aclaro el modelo trae la información solo no es mostrada en el archivo .cshtml.

```
@Model  Login.Models.ViewModels.CorreoViewModel
```

Intente así:

```
Hola. @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.cNombre)

Hola. @Model.cNombre

Hola. @Html.Display("cNombre")
```

El valor del campo no se imprime solo el el dato como tal... que estaré haciendo mal ?. Gracias.

Comment: Por que haces esto `return Redirect("~/Acceso/Index")`?. No debes acceder a la vista directamente, por que no haces un `RedirectToAction()`?. Y por otra parte, en que vista defines la directiva `@Model  Login.Models.ViewModels.CorreoViewModel` ?

Comment: Saludos Rafael, el return Redirect("~/Acceso/Index") lo hago para regresar al inicio del Login, después de enviar el correo. Debo enviar una ventana modal con el mensaje de que el correo ha sido enviado y revise su bandeja... etc, así que solo de momento lo envió a index. Respecto a en que vista defino la directiva de @Model no lo hago.. solo llamo a la clase que llama al template .cshtml, y ahí defino el Model al inicio e intento llamar al Nombre y PIN.

Comment: La verdad no lo entiendo, puedes indicar la Vista Index.cshtml o la vista donde quieres mostrar Nombre y PIN?

Comment: Amigo Rafael la acción llama a vista de Index del controlador Acceso es pantalla de inicio con ese no hay problema, ahí dirijo al usuario después de enviar correo. Mi problema es que el correo que le hago llegar al usuario donde visualizara la información (template .cshtml) que incluye 2 campos del nombre de usuario y pin, no muestra los valores de los campos mencionados. en el código inicial se aprecian las funciones para llamar al template. Al final he colocado Model Login.Models.ViewModels.CorreoViewModel es la primer línea del archivo .cshtml y luego uso @Model.cNombre u otros sin exito

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que solo estas leyendo el texto plano de la vista, no pasa por ningún helper o método en el que pases tu modelo, lo que yo suelo en emails, es generar el layout/vista y en los lugares donde quieras poner datos los cambias por {numero} y hacer un string.Format(htmlString,"Dato1","Dato2")

ejemplo:

SoportePIN:

```
Hola. {0}  
Tu PIN es {1}
```

Codigo:

```
var vHtml = string.Format(EmailTemplate("SoportePIN"),"Nombre Generico","12345")
```

Es una opción.